# C++ MySQL program crashes with error 255 on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, netbeans, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have this simple C++ program:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: marek
 *
 * Created on 1. listopadu 2017, 22:33
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>



using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout << endl;
cout << "running select as a messege" << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://10.0.0.6:3306", "root", "*****");

  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("mysql");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "̣# ERR: SQLException in "    << __FILE__; 
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl; 
  cout << "̣# ERR: " << e.what(); 
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl; 
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;




std::cout << "hello world pc 5 mysql\n"; 

#ifdef __linux__ 
    std::cout << "__linux__\n";  
#elif defined(__unix__)
    std::cout << "__unix__\n";  
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    std::cout << "_WIN64\n";  
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    std::cout << "_WIN32\n";  
#endif


#if __WORDSIZE == 64 
    std::cout << "64 bit\n";
#else 
    std::cout << "32 bit\n";  
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Its important to note:

- MySQL server (MariaDB) is running on Raspi Pi 3 on local subnet.
- I am able to connect to DB for example from HeidiSQL
- The same script is build build successfully on Raspi pi 3

My IDE is NetBeans with following settings:

- Tools > options > C/C++ compilers is MiniGW QT with everything store in default installation folder. For me C:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\, and make command is C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe.
- To this compiller I am also including directories Mysql connector C++ 1.1.9. also in the default installation directory. For me it would be c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9

My Windows path is set to:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;
c:\msys\1.0\bin\;
C:\MinGW\bin;
c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\mingw53_32\bin\;
c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\;
c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\mingw53_32\bin\designer.exe;
c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\;
c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe;
C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib\;
C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib\plugin\;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;
c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9\include\;
```

After a long struggle I've been able to make a build on NetBeans Windows. Inside of the same folder, where my executable is being stored I copied in a mysqlcppconn.dll, which was originally missing.

If I run this version of my program from **Netbeans** I get:

```
running select as a messege
RUN FAILED (exit value 255, total time: 2s)
```

**Windows** CMD I get:

```
nothing. 
just windows dialog of program crashes
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time for your debugger.

Comment: Debugger in Netbeans you mean? I tried that and I get: 
- selected console type is not supported in your configuration, using external terminal instead. After that debugger starts and new DOS window is opened with error from Netbeans:
- Signla receive: SIGSEGV ( segmentation failed) for program Hello-world-7-pc-mysql, pid 6508. Than I get this error once again. Than i Get crash with this in  Callstack:

Comment: wcslen () at null:
mysqlcppconn!??0MySQL_Driver@mysql@sql@@QAE@ABVSQLString@2@@Z () at null:
?? () at null:
mysqlcppconn!??0MySQL_Driver@mysql@sql@@QAE@ABVSQLString@2@@Z () at null:
main (argc=1, argv=0xdf6f18) at C:\\Users\\marek\\Documents\\c++ projects\\hello-world-7-pc-mysql\\main.cpp:51

which points to line with driver->connect I believe.

Comment: You never check that `driver` is not null.

Comment: i just did. Program will crash exactly at  con = driver->connect("tcp://10.0.0.6:3306", "root", "FTQERJSC"); and never go on next line. I put right on the next line simple cout, and get nothing.
 cout << "before connect" << endl;
  con = driver->connect("tcp://10.0.0.6:3306", "root", "*****");
  cout << "after connect" << endl;
  cout << con << endl;

Comment: coudl blocked these kind of communication router? I mean port 3306?

Comment: after 2 more days I am still stucked.